# Leetcode 3Sum: why is result duplicated?

Tags: python

I am trying the [15. 3Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/) code challenge on LeetCode:

> Given an integer array `nums`, return all the triplets `[nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]]` such that `i != j, i != k`, and `j != k`, and `nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0`.
>
> Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]
> Output: [[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]
> ```

Here is my attempt:

```
class Solution(object):
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        if len(nums) < 3:
            return []
        nums.sort()
        ret_val = []
        for i in range(len(nums) - 2):
            if i - 1 >= 0 and nums[i - 1] == nums[i]:
                while nums[i - 1] == nums[i] and i < len(nums) - 2:
                    i += 1
                if nums[i - 1] == nums[i]:
                    break
            j = i + 1
            k = len(nums) - 1
            # This is our target sum
            target = -nums[i]            
            while j < k:
                if j - 1 != i and nums[j - 1] == nums[j]:
                    while nums[j - 1] == nums[j] and j < k:
                        j += 1
                elif k + 1 != len(nums) and nums[k + 1] == nums[k]:
                    while nums[k + 1] == nums[k] and j < k:
                        k -= 1
                else:
                    if nums[j] + nums[k] == target:
                        ret_val.append([nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]])
                        j += 1
                        k -= 1
                    elif nums[j] + nums[k] < target:
                        j += 1
                    else:
                        k -= 1
        return ret_val
```

There is apparently a bug in my code that I couldn't figure out, even after running the Python Debugger. My code gives the wrong result when I use the input of `[-11, 1, -12, -12, 10]`. It creates an unnecessary duplicate in the answer. I've never seen this happen before, but Python seems to run the `for` loop one too many times.

The expected output should be `[[-11, 1, 10]]`, but it instead gives `[[-11, 1, 10], [-11, 1, 10]]`. Another interesting thing I discovered is that by removing either one or both instances of -12, it ends up giving the correct answer of `[[-11, 1, 10]]`.

What is the problem in my code?

Comment: You told us the input, but could you explain what your program should do, what you get as a result and what you expect?

Comment: Just for fun: that's a one-liner if you use `itertools` from the standard library: `print({tuple(sorted(combi)) for combi in itertools.combinations(nums, 3) if sum(combi) == 0})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your outer loop will sometimes increment `i` (the loop variable). This is not good, because that incremented `i` value is scheduled to be `i`'s value in a next iteration of that loop, and so you will have two iterations happening with the same value for `i`.

Note how Python's `for i in range` iteration does not take into account any increment you apply to `i` in one of the iterations. The full range of values will be iterated, no matter what you do with `i` in the mean time. This is different from more traditional `for` loop constructs that you find in other programming languages:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < len(nums) - 2; i++)
```

...as in that case the loop's `i++` will just act on whatever value `i` has at that moment, taking into account any change you made to `i` during an iteration. Again, this is not how it works with an iterator such as Python's `range` function returns.

The solution is to just exit the current iteration when you would have wanted to increment `i`, since you know that the *next* iteration will have that incremented value for `i` anyhow.

So change this piece of code:

```
   if i - 1 >= 0 and nums[i - 1] == nums[i]:
        while nums[i - 1] == nums[i] and i < len(nums) - 2:
            i += 1
        if nums[i - 1] == nums[i]:                
            break
```

to this:

```
    if i - 1 >= 0 and nums[i - 1] == nums[i]:
        continue
```

That will solve the issue.

Comment: You're totally right! Now it makes sense why removing -12 fixed the solution. Thanks!